# QGIS select by expression Modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler, select-by-expression

I'm trying to build a model which should select polygons based on selected polylines. The polygons share attribute values with the polylines. In this case the field "Outlet" (polygon) contains the values from "Name" (polylines).
If i run the extract by expression from the toolbox with the following expression: `is_selected('Polyline',get_feature('Polyline','Name',"Outlet"))` I get the correct result.

[image]

I like to make the inputs variable, also the attribute fields. So transfering the toolbox to the model designer I get the error message: *syntax error, unexpected $end
Error encountered while running Extract by expression*. So I tried some things and found out that in the Modeler I have to change the expression to `is_selected(@polyline,get_feature(@polyline,@name,@outlet)) is not null`. Unfortunately the result layer is then empty.
[image]